# Nonce generated in WordPress route function working but returns "invalid nonce" when defined in wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, rest, routes, nonce

This one is frustrating and the answer is *probably* obvious but I don't know what's wrong.

I've built a route in a headless WordPress back end which allows / will allow users in a React JS app to add data to an acf repeater field attached to a custom post type.  I'm using Postman to test with X-WP-Nonce and Authorization headers set although pertaining to the question below it's X-WP-Nonce which is relevant.

As long as I generate the nonce within the route function using: `$rmgNonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');` and then verify it like so...

```
    $nonce = $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Nonce' );
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'wp_rest' ) ) {
        echo "received nonce: " . $nonce;
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_nonce', 'Invalid nonce.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
```

...it works.

However, if I define the nonce in wp-config.php as follows: `define('MY_APP_NONCE', '92630df8ee');` and try to verify it like so...

```
    // Check the nonce
    $nonce = $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Nonce' );
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, MY_APP_NONCE ) ) {
        echo "received nonce: " . $nonce;
        echo "MY_APP_NONCE: " . MY_APP_NONCE;
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_nonce', 'Invalid nonce.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
```

...it triggers the WP_Error in the return statement of the above.

Bafflingly, the echo statements in the second example both display the same value (92630df8ee) so the value defined in wp-config.php is being picked up. It actually returns 'invalid nonce' even if I hard code the nonce into the verify_nonce function instead of 'MY_APP_NONCE' as in: `if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, '92630df8ee' ) ) { ...`

What am I missing here? For completeness sake, the full function is below but I think the above is the salient stuff.

Many thanks.

```
function update_maritimeimage( $request ) {
    // $rmgNonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
    // echo "rmgNonce: " . $rmgNonce;
    
    // Get the ID parameter from the request
    $id = $request->get_param( 'id' );

    // Check if the ID is valid
    if ( !is_numeric( $id ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_id', 'Invalid ID.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    }

    // Get the maritimeimage custom post
    $maritimeimage = get_post( $id );

    // Check if the post exists and is of type maritimeimage
    if ( empty( $maritimeimage ) || $maritimeimage->post_type !== 'maritimeimagearchive' ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_post', 'Invalid post.', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    }

    // Check if the user is authorized to edit the post
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $id ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'unauthorized', 'Unauthorized.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }

    // Get the contains_people custom field from the request
    $contains_people = $request->get_param( 'contains_people' );
    $researcher_id = $request->get_param( 'researcher_id' );

    // Check if the contains_people parameter is present
    if ( !$contains_people ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'missing_field', 'Missing field.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    }

    // Check the nonce
    $nonce = $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Nonce' );
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, MY_APP_NONCE ) ) {
        echo "received nonce: " . $nonce;
        echo "MY_APP_NONCE: " . MY_APP_NONCE;
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_nonce', 'Invalid nonce.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }

    // Check the authorization headers
    $auth_header = $request->get_header( 'Authorization' );
    if ( empty( $auth_header ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'unauthorized', 'Unauthorized.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }

    $auth_parts = explode( ' ', $auth_header );
    var_dump("auth_parts: " . $auth_parts[0] . ", " . $auth_parts[1]);
    if ( count( $auth_parts ) != 2 || $auth_parts[0] != 'Bearer' ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_credentials', 'Invalid credentials1.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }

    // Get the current value of the repeater field
    $repeater_field = get_field( 'researcher_input_image_contains_people', $id );
    if ( !is_array( $repeater_field ) ) {
        $repeater_field = array();
    }

    // Check if there is already a row with the same researcher_id
    $row_exists = false;
    foreach ( $repeater_field as $row ) {
        if ( $row['researcher_id'] == $researcher_id ) {
            $row_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Add a new row to the repeater field if a row with the same researcher_id doesn't already exist
    if ( !$row_exists ) {
        $new_row = array(
        'researcher_image_contains_people' => $contains_people == 'true' ? '1' : '0', 
        'researcher_id' => $researcher_id
    );
        $repeater_field[] = $new_row;

        // Update the post meta with the new value of the repeater field
        update_field( 'researcher_input_image_contains_people', $repeater_field, $id );
    }


    // Return the updated post
    $response = new WP_REST_Response( $maritimeimage );
      $response->set_status( 200 );

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Where is the value "92630df8ee" coming from? Just something you made up?

Comment: It's the value of the nonce.